# Flutter - How to update UI (list) after calling a function at regular intervals?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, state

API service:

```
class APIService
  static Future<List<myModel>> getList() async {
 ///Call API 
  return myList;
}
```

HomePage:

```
                              child: Text(
                                   APIService.myList.length.toString(),
                                                         ),
```

Main:

```
      void main() {
            var time = const Duration(seconds: 10);
            Timer.periodic(
                time,
                (timer) => {
              API service.getList();
                    });

    runApp(MyApp());
  }
```

From the code it should be clear that I cannot call setState in APIService. How do I update the UI after the function APIService.getList() gets called every 10 seconds from the main method?

Comment: use GetX controller to update UI

Comment: You can use stream builder for that